# Unable to get the right output for average number

Tags: java

I am creating this program that has the values for rows set to 10 and then it adds it to the board class.. Later on, the user has to enter a value less than or equal to the average of the total rows which is 10, If he enters the wrong value, the program will ask him to enter correct one however, average of 10 is 5 and i can enter number from between 0-5 without getting the "please enter correct value" message, however, when i try to do that with my program, it says 5,4,3,2,1 are incorrect numbers and only accepts 0.. Here is my program

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Calculate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int co,row,col;

        Board b= new Board();
        row=10;
        b.setRow(row);
        System.out.println("Enter number less than or equal to the averange of rows");
        Scanner src= new Scanner(System.in);
        col=getRow(src);
        System.out.println(col);
    }

    private static int getRow(Scanner c) {
        int b=-1;
        Board o= new Board();
        while(b<0 || b>o.getRow()/2)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter correct row");
                b=c.nextInt();
        }


        return b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Presumably, when you do `Board o= new Board();`, the new board has `row` of `0`. A `new` board is not the same board that you set row to 10 on.

Comment: @khelwood thanks.. Tho is there a way to call the old object in the method?

Comment: You pass it in: `getRow(Scanner c, Board o)`

Comment: You can pass the object into the method as an argument.

Comment: thanks it worked.. Please post ur answer so i can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
Board o= new Board();
```

inside `getRow`, you are making a new board with (presumably) `row` at zero. It is not the same board that you construct in `main` and set `row` to 10.

To pass board from `main` into `getRow`, add it as an argument:

```
private static int getRow(Scanner c, Board o) {
    int b=-1;
    while(b<0 || b>o.getRow()/2) {
        System.out.println("Please enter correct row");
        b=c.nextInt();
    }
    return b;
}
```

and pass it in when you call `getRow` from `main`:

```
col = getRow(src, b);
```